# DAT Files containing raw data converted to legible text

Tags: vim

I used the ubuntu distribution to operate VIM and a DAT File that contains lines along the following:

```
0000030801549200000308015492          0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000109500010957REG0001095REGIPY       1989010100010101Y99991231N    YYQ   REG        R
```

The DAT file is approximately 3GB and Has about 18+million lines. I am trying to decipher this raw data via VIM but I am not sure how to do this as this is something totally out of my knowledge base. I would think it is binary; however, I see other information in there which is confusing and may not be altered solely from a binary point of view. Some help would be appreciated. I wanted to put it into a TXT format or a CSV format and uploaded into MYSQL at the end.

Comment: What is the output of `file yourfile.dat`?

Comment: @terdon..hey thanks for the response. What do you mean?

Comment: There is a command called `file`, and I would like to see the output of running that command on _your_ DAT file. So if your file is called `my_file.dat`, you would need to open a new terminal window, and run `file my_file.dat`. That will give us some basic information about what this file is. Sorry about the confusion, the name of the command being `file` makes for some very confusing sentences!

Comment: Could it be a registry hives file? Those have a REGF header that looks like what you have there.  If so this will open it: `import numpy as np 
content = np.loadtxt('{file}.dat', unpack = True)` (those are TWO lines) and content will be readable.